# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' py 2.7 to py 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am a Python learner and new for stackoverflow. The following code was written in Python 2.7 and when I try to run it using Python 3.6, I stack with the below error. I read many previous posts on that error but I remain unable to solve my code. kindly indicate to me which line/s need to fix and how.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-db1423a8bf7b> in <module>
     71 
     72 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 73     main()

<ipython-input-52-db1423a8bf7b> in main()
     54     csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutput, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
     55 
---> 56     csvWriter.writerow(["Ticker", "DocIndex","IndexLink", "Description", "FilingDate","NewFilingDate"])
     57     csvOutput.close()
     58 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

```
import os,sys,csv,time # "time" helps to break for the url visiting 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Need to install this package manually using pip
                                # We only import part of the Beautifulsoup4
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen

os.chdir('E:\Python\python_exercise') # The location of your file "LongCompanyList.csv"
companyListFile = "CompanyList.csv" # a csv file with the list of company ticker symbols and names (the file has a line with headers)
IndexLinksFile = "IndexLinks.csv" # a csv file (output of the current script) with the list of index links for each firm (the file has a line with headers)

def getIndexLink(tickerCode,FormType):
    csvOutput = open(IndexLinksFile,"a+b") # "a+b" indicates that we are adding lines rather than replacing lines
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutput, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    urlLink = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK="+tickerCode+"&type="+FormType+"&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100"
    pageRequest = urllib.Request(urlLink)
    pageOpen = urllib.urlopen(pageRequest)
    pageRead = pageOpen.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageRead,"html.parser")

    #Check if there is a table to extract / code exists in edgar database
    try:
        table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "tableFile2" })
    except:
        print ("No tables found or no matching ticker symbol for ticker symbol for"+tickerCode)
        return -1

    docIndex = 1
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        cells = row.findAll("td")
        if len(cells)==5:
            if cells[0].text.strip() == FormType:
                link = cells[1].find("a",{"id": "documentsbutton"})
                docLink = "https://www.sec.gov"+link['href']
                description = cells[2].text.encode('utf8').strip() #strip take care of the space in the beginning and the end
                filingDate = cells[3].text.encode('utf8').strip()
                newfilingDate = filingDate.replace("-","_")  ### <=== Change date format from 2012-1-1 to 2012_1_1 so it can be used as part of 10-K file names
                csvWriter.writerow([tickerCode, docIndex, docLink, description, filingDate,newfilingDate])
                docIndex = docIndex + 1
    csvOutput.close()


def main():  
    FormType = "10-K"   ### <=== Type your document type here
    nbDocPause = 10 ### <=== Type your number of documents to download in one batch
    nbSecPause = 0 ### <=== Type your pausing time in seconds between each batch

    csvFile = open(companyListFile,"r") #<===open and read from a csv file with the list of company ticker symbols (the file has a line with headers)
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile,delimiter=",")
    csvData = list(csvReader)

    csvOutput = open(IndexLinksFile,"a+b") #<===open and write to a csv file which will include the list of index links. New rows will be appended.
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutput, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    csvWriter.writerow(["Ticker", "DocIndex","IndexLink", "Description", "FilingDate","NewFilingDate"])
    csvOutput.close()

    i = 1
    for rowData in csvData[1:]:
        ticker = rowData[0]
        getIndexLink(ticker,FormType)
        if i%nbDocPause == 0:
            print (i)
            print ("Pause for "+str(nbSecPause)+" second .... ")
            time.sleep(float(nbSecPause))
        i=i+1

    csvFile.close()
    print ("done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you run `2to3.py` on it?

Comment: By the way, `'E:\Python\python_exercise'` is an accident waiting to happen.  It works right now, but if you had a filename starting `'E:\Python\n...` then `\n` would get translated to a newline, `'E:\Python\r..` would have a carriage-return in it, and so on.  On Windows, either use `/` or a *raw string*:  `r'E:\Python\python_exercise'`.

Comment: @Patrick Artner I am trying to use 2to3.py but still struggling how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open your file in binary mode:

> ```
> csvOutput = open(IndexLinksFile,"a+b")
> ```

If you open as binary you need to write binary - you are only writing "normal" text, so the simlpest fix would probably be to write strings:

```
csvOutput = open(IndexLinksFile,"a")  # simple utf text file
```

If you open a file binary, you also need to write binary to it - hence the error.

Simply changing `a+b` to `a` might break other things in your code or the application that reads your created file - test if it works before putting it into production.

You can no copy 2.7 code to 3.x code *as is*.

Doku:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

> [...] The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. mode can be `'r'` when the file will only be read, `'w'` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and `'a'` opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. `'r+'` opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; `'r'` will be assumed if it’s omitted.
>
> Normally, files are opened in text mode, that means, you read and write strings from and to the file, which are encoded in a specific encoding. If encoding is not specified, the default is platform dependent (see open()). `'b'` appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects. This mode should be used for all files that don’t contain text.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The error has gone, but I received another error saying:
 AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'Request' 

Previous posts on stackoverflow show using "import urllib.request" to solve it, but it remains with me. May you advise please?

Comment: @Mohamed this is a different error - I am not very familiar with url-requests and scraping differences in py 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Artner I solved it using the following website transfer from py 2 to py 3
https://pythonconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, you'll want to work with Unicode strings, not binary (`b`) data as much as possible.

- Change the `"a+b"` file opening modes to `"a+"` to get files you can write strings into; they'll be converted to UTF-8 (which you can change with the `encoding` parameter to `open`).
- Remove those `.encode()` calls you have; BeautifulSoup is Unicode-string native, and once your files are open in text mode, as described above, that encoding will be done for you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The error has gone, but I received another error saying:

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'Request'

Previous posts on stackoverflow show using "import urllib.request" to solve it, but it remains with me. May you advise please?

Comment: You should be using the http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ library to do HTTP requests with your sanity intact :)

Comment: Thanks @AKX. it seems using it requiring lots of change in the code which may be hard for me. Any other thoughts?